# Does diagonal double limit imply double limit?

Tags: limits, double-sequence

If double indexed sequence $\{a_{m,n}\}$ has the same limit along each diagonal, i.e.,
$$
\lim_{m,n\to\infty\\ m/n\to c} a_{m,n} = a
$$
for each $c\in(0,\infty)$, it is not necessarily true that the double limit $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}a_{m,n}$ exists. For example, consider $a_{m,n} = m/n^2$.

However, I wonder if things might get different if $c\in[0,\infty]$. That is, if
$$
\lim_{m,n\to\infty\\ m/n\to c} a_{m,n} = a
$$
for $c\in[0,\infty]$. Do we now have $\lim_{m,n\to\infty}a_{m,n} = a$? It seems correct but I cannot prove it. Any hint or a counterexample?

Comment: No, consider $a_{m,n}=0$ except for $a_{n,n^2}=1$. Each diagonal will eventually be $0$ but obviously the limit is not $0$.

Comment: I'm genuinely not sure what the limits in the question mean. Are the quantifiers $\forall \varepsilon~ \forall \delta~ \exists M~ \exists N~ \forall ((n,m), n>N \land m>M \land |m/n-c|<\delta)$?

Comment: Or is it additive: $\forall \varepsilon~ \forall \delta~ \exists M~ \exists N~ \forall ((n,m), n>N \land m>M \land |m-cn|<\delta)$? The difference is whether for each direction you want to take narrowing cylinders or narrowing cones, and QC_QAOA's example doesn't work for the cones.